# How do i create winxp style controls

Tags: vb.net, controls, xp-theme

I am trying to make my controls look as cool as xp theme enabled controls like gradient fill background in container controls and colour thames support etc

I am not finding a way to start. from where can i start doing it?

I am trying to do it in vb.net

Edited:

EnableXpVisualStyles() 
I found it to enable visual styles but didn't give me visual thames to apply. So in order to apply thames or colour schemes what should i do?

What other commands should i use with combination with it? as I have seen my application giving ugly look even applying that command and other program showing nice loook in my win2003 server

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before your show your form:

Application.EnableVisualStyles()

Comment: does it also works in win2003. I want my application to show up with winxp styles in win2003 and win2000 as well

Comment: @KoolKabin: I believe it works for Windows 2003, but I do not know how to support it for Windows 2000, as that OS predates XP.

Comment: I have tried it... if the visual thames are enabled in win2003 then it applies but if not fails. can we create own xp like theme and apply it

Comment: @KoolKabin: By default on Windows 2003 no XP like themes are enabled as the service is not running, that is likely your problem there. Random forum post I found that explains the steps: http://forums.webhostautomation.com/showthread.php?t=7810

However I don't know nearly enough about how to create a theme from scratch. All the work I have done is just getting a basic window running for small applications.